# How do I fix this "Bad MAC" error from EthCrypto.js?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt messages with EthCrypto.js.

I am getting a signature on the front end via

```
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
          const account = accounts[0];
          const signatureHash = await web3.value.eth.personal.sign('Signature verification for video file encryption', account);
```

The account address is `0x500694d00eFc0315Cac629b83Dfd11C8b038AfAa`

Encryption works fine:

```
        const signature = '0x27b76aa76e75d3a723883629b532b771ec860edb338b0c8421244bbd1f3d0f7078eb7bd17aad73823b0d401e917e7edcc5ca267a34623f4c7e4b3cefbfab7ac31b'
        const plaintext = 'test message'
        const publicKey = EthCrypto.recoverPublicKey(
            signature,
            EthCrypto.hash.keccak256('Signature verification for video file encryption')
        );
        
        const encrypted = await EthCrypto.encryptWithPublicKey(publicKey, plaintext);
        return EthCrypto.cipher.stringify(encrypted);
```

I get back an object which looks right:

```
{
  "iv": "89f37bdafdcb156603804be2bbc4acb3",
  "ephemPublicKey": "04a0e2b193a5e00442f72c69ca035e9f29d9d98e719b8e86d172f14dae1912e443bb35333a776a43b63d6b87108e1f0b1bf0fcdab0e47a7669da9d80b7d7e644ba",
  "ciphertext": "46d5b09c5aad80cbe9e264133afa13e0",
  "mac": "c8237beb6bcee4f5afd361ce0d20364e4bfa533cb530fd1c3821c6e220b8bf7a"
}
```

then stringify it: `const encrypted = await EthCrypto.encryptWithPublicKey(publicKey, plaintext);`

The resulting string destringifies into the original object just fine:         `const parsed =  EthCrypto.cipher.parse(ciphertext);`

But when I try to decrypt with the private key `const decrypted = await EthCrypto.decryptWithPrivateKey(privateKey,parsed);` I get a Bad MAC error.

Why is this? It seems like a bug. How do I fix it?

Comment: @pubkey I notice you are the library author. There is probably some incredibly obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Possibly it is your data. Post a complete example, including the generation of the keys and the signature, so that a repro is possible.

Comment: Updated. Please take a look. I suspect it has to do with the way I am getting/storing/processing the signature.

Comment: For my test, I generated the key pair with `createIdentity()`. With these keys, your workflow works from signing, to reconstructing the public key, and encrypting with the public key, to decrypting with the private key. Maybe your keys are not related. It's hard to say since you didn't post the private key.

Comment: I am obviously not going to pass a private key here.

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with a difference between the way the web3.js signature function works and the way EthCrypto does it.

Comment: *I am obviously not going to pass a private key here* You are not supposed to post production keys, but test data (should be obvious). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135888/how-do-i-create-a-signature-with-web3-js-which-ethcrypto-can-process-properly/135900?noredirect=1#comment156154_135900

The issue is that web3.eth.personal.sign() appends additional characters to the string. Therefore, recovering the public key or address from the signature needs to be done thusly:

`const address2 = EthCrypto.recover( signature, EthCrypto.hash.keccak256( "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message ) );`